# Вопрос по адаптивной верстке

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, responsive, адаптивность

Сверстал макет, делаю адаптив. Нужно уменьшить заголовки h2 и отступы padding(top и bottom в каждой секции). Так как отступы в каждой секции разные, хочу уменьшить их синхронно(на одинаковое количество px, что бы они оставались разными) и отдельно уменьшить заголовки h2(т.е на другое количество px, нежели отступы). Как это сделать ???

Код примерно такой -->

```html
<section class="one">
  <h2 class="h2_one">...</h2>
  <p class="paragraph_one">...</p>
</section>

<section class="two">
  <h2 class="h2_two">...</h2>
  <p class="paragraph_two">...</p>
</section>

<section class="three">
  <h2 class="h2_three">...</h2>
  <p class="paragraph_three">...</p>
</section>

<section class="four">
  <h2 class="h2_four">...</h2>
  <p class="paragraph_four">...</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Задавать отступы и размеры шрифта в относительных единицах измерения, а не в пикселях

Comment: Хотелось бы нагляднее

Comment: Третий день не могу решить, как сделать наилучшим образом

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/css-units

Comment: Это не помогло мне, я знаю как работают эти единицы

Comment: в чем тогда вопрос? Если тебе просто надо уменьшать при адаптиве отступы блоков то задай одинаковые отступы блокам и с ними работай, а в блоках сделай контейнеры и им уже задавай дополнительные отступы, которые не меняются.

Comment: В этом и вопрос, что  бы синхронно изменить отступы не затрагивая  заголовков и не добавляя никаких контейнеров

Comment: т.е. игнорируя специально предназначенные для этого возможности?

Comment: Добавлять, что то в html ради стилей не очень хорошо и есть методы проще этого. Это только зря увеличит вложенность

Comment: `есть методы проще этого` какие например?)

Comment: ⇊⇊⇊ например ⇊⇊⇊

Comment: добавь в вопрос условия, что нельзя менять исходный html и относительные единицы измерения не подходят. Не вижу в единственном ответе на вопрос, что соблюдено условие про `синхронно` , так что не понимаю, что ты мне в пример приводишь. Перебивать css каждого элемента отдельно - это, по моему, не синхронно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здраствуй! для простоты работы в таких случаях создавай дополнительные классы. В частности рекомендую использовать БЭМ методологию и почитать статью организация отступов в верстке. В твоем случае можно здлеать так:

1) Добавить для секции класc .section 
2) Сделать универсальный клас для заголовков например .section__title
3) для каждого тайтла добавить модификатор .section__title--one, .section__title--two и тд.

и так каждый на определенном брейкпоинте адаптировать.